Can we say "the audience is prohibited from using the flashlight"?
In the driving competition, the audience are prohibited from using the flashlight when taking photos. Can we say

the audience is prohibited from using the flashlight

In the Oxford dictionary, we can also find such example sentence

The audience was/were clapping for 10 minutes.


"Flash photography prohibited."  "The applause lasted 10 minutes."

First, "the" flashlight implies there would be one, but an audience might have many flashlights, so "The audience is prohibited from using flashlights," would be correct.

It depends on locale on date whether "audience" is a singular or plural noun. Google Ngram Viewer shows that, in their corpus, until about 1850, "audience were," was not uncommon, though now "audience is," is the norm.

In American English, a "flashlight" provides steady illumination (what might be termed a "torch" on the other side of the pond), but a "flash," or "strobe" provides a burst of light for photography.


sigh That is English as She Is Spoke. When other languages were being codified, such as by the French Académie Française, it appears English speakers were otherwise occupied. Quel dommage

(sigh)? ... but where's the fun in codified languages?

Can you imagine a certain president putting some moron or madman in charge of the newly instituted Academy for Great American English?

@JavaLatte, yes -- I merely intended it as a wry comment, perhaps a bit seedy.
